# Consulta de traer datos BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos días Gente, le estoy dando vueltas a una consulta que, parecería simple pero no puedo encontrarle la vuelta. estoy desarrollando un sistema de reserva
en la cual fracciona cada 00:30 minutos y se reserva por rango de 01:00:00 o 01:30:00  tengo una tabla reserva id,fecha,hora,estado  con todas la horas posibles con un estado 0 para libre y 1 para reservado. 
El tema es que si tengo una reserva ejemplo de 10:00:00 a 11;00  y una de 12:00:00 a 13:00:00  y quiero hacer una de 11:30 a 13:30 me la trae como si fuera correcta estando reservado parte de ese rango. bueno espero que se entiende si me pueden dar una mano se lo agradeceré mucho

y tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT *, ADDTIME(`hora`, '01:00:00') as hasta 
FROM `reservas` 
WHERE (`hora` BETWEEN hora and  ADDTIME(`hora`, '01:00:00'))
AND `dia` = '2017-11-29' 
AND `estado` = '1'
```

Comment: No tienes en la tabla reserva una columna con la fora de fin de reserva?, tienes que siempre agregarle una hora a la hora de reserva?

Comment: Tienes que hacer esto con sql obligatoriamente? Porque creo que se manejaría mucho mas fácil desde el ambiente de desarrollo con el lenguaje que sea que estás usando para tu sistema

Comment: si por que serian las horas permitidas.

Answer (score 0):

Gente muchas gracias lo resolví de la siguiente manera, contando cuantos ocupados existen dentro de ese rango de hora si existe uno no lo trae
Lo dejo por si alguno lo precisa para algo

```
SELECT *, ADDTIME(`hora`, '01:00:00') as hasta
  FROM `reservas` r1
 WHERE ( (select count(*)
            from reservas r2
           where r2.hora >= r1.hora
             and r2.hora <= ADDTIME(r1.hora, '01:00:00')
             AND r2.dia = '2017-11-29'
             AND r2.estado = 0 ) = 0 ) 
  AND r1.dia = '2017-11-29'
  AND r1.estado = 1
```

Comment: No llego a ver como esto puede resolver tu pregunta inicial. Esta consulta no me parece que te diga si es posible hacer una reserva de 11:30 a 13:30.